# Разделить массив на интервалы с шагом

Tags: python, массивы, numpy

Есть массив:

```py
arr = [1.112, 1.113, 1.114, 1.111, 1.221, 1.223, 1.321, 1.021, 1.03, 2.0, 3.6, 4.2]
```

Необходимо разделить его на элементы с шагом: `0.1`, начиная со значений: `1` заканчивая `2`.

Моё решение следующее:
Пробежаться циклом по массиву, проверять, что если элемент попадает в диапазон от `1` до `1.1`, то добавлять его в список. Затем сдвигать шаг и проверять уже в диапазоне от `1.1` до `1.2`, если так, то добавлять в другой список.

Это работает, если массив маленький, а если большой, то время выполнения значительно.

Как оптимизировать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть метод [groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). Но какого-то красивого решения для этой задачи не могу придумать. Остаётся проблема того, что получившийся список групп не упорядочен по возрастанию интервалов. Однако, может, кому-то будет полезно.

```
from itertools import groupby

arr = [1.112, 1.113, 1.114, 1.111, 1.221, 1.223, 1.321, 1.021, 1.03, 2.0, 3.6, 4.2]


result = groupby(arr, key=lambda x: int(x * 10) if 1 <= x < 2 else -1)

for key, vals in result:
    print(key / 10, list(vals))
```

https://ideone.com/Xzm8gU

Answer (score 3):

Решение с использованием модуля Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd   #  pip install pandas

s = pd.Series(arr)

bins = np.concatenate(([-np.inf], np.arange(1, 2, 0.1), [np.inf]))
```

список границ интервалов:

```
In [25]: bins
Out[25]: array([-inf,  1. ,  1.1,  1.2,  1.3,  1.4,  1.5,  1.6,  1.7,  1.8,  1.9,  inf])
```

решение и результат:

```
In [26]: s.groupby(pd.cut(arr, bins), observed=True).apply(lambda x: x.to_list())
Out[26]:
(1.0, 1.1]                   [1.021, 1.03]
(1.1, 1.2]    [1.112, 1.113, 1.114, 1.111]
(1.2, 1.3]                  [1.221, 1.223]
(1.3, 1.4]                         [1.321]
(1.9, inf]                 [2.0, 3.6, 4.2]
dtype: object
```

результат в виде "Vanilla Python list":

```
In [27]: s.groupby(pd.cut(arr, bins), observed=True).apply(lambda x: x.to_list()).to_list()
Out[27]:
[[1.021, 1.03],
 [1.112, 1.113, 1.114, 1.111],
 [1.221, 1.223],
 [1.321],
 [2.0, 3.6, 4.2]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Дробная часть чисел из списка позволяет понять, в какой по номеру новый список попадает число. Учитывая шаг 0.1, из 1.221 получаем 0.221, потом 2.21, и наконец целое 2, которое является индексом нового списка.

`NewRange[int((arr[i] - 1) * 10)].append(arr[i])`

Однако и приведенный в вопросе подход линейный от числа элементов, и не будет особо медленным.

Answer (score 2):

```
arr = [1.112, 1.113, 1.114, 1.111, 1.221, 1.223, 1.321, 1.021, 1.03, 2.0, 3.6, 4.2]

dct = {}

for i in arr:
    if not 1<=i<=2:
        continue
    key = round(i, 1)
    dct[key] = dct.get(key, [])
    dct[key].append(i)

print(dct)
```